# Create a relationship across multiple tables that allows only one entry per date

Tags: relationship, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a database that will be used by multiple teams in my company that displays their daily stats.

When you open up the database I have a combo box that allows you to select your team name. Once you make your selection, your form appears with your team stats for the day. (In reality it's just one form that has a subform with a query. The query is updated when you select your team from the combo box)

Each team has their own separate set of stats for each day and they are only allowed one entry per day. Not every single team has the same category of stats. This is an example of some of my tables

Quality Stats Table:
**Team Name | Daily # | Actual # | Goal # | DateOfEntry**

Productivity Table:
**Team Name | Percentage | DateOfEntry**

Stop Ship Table:
**Team Name | Yes/No | DateOfEntry**

How do I make it so that each team can only have one entry in each table per day?
I have my Team Names linked across all the tables, but I am having a hard time enforcing the one entry per date restriction

I am very new at access and I am still trying to figure it out. I would greatly appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a multiple-field unique index on each of those tables.  Here is an example for the `Quality Stats` table ...

```vb
strSQL = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxQualTeamDate ON [Quality Stats] ([Team Name], DateOfEntry)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
```

The same thing can also be done through the [Access user interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce).  If you prefer to go that route, it might still be helpful to execute the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` statement I gave you and then open the table in *Design View* to see how Access presents it there.